# Custom ImageView does not fire performClick

Tags: android, onclick, android-camera, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I have a shutter button which implements it's own listener for handling focus and click events
Here,there are two methods,one for focus and another for click.I find that these methods are not being called...

My custom view extends an ImageView is as follows:

```
public class ShutterButton extends ImageView {

public ShutterButton(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ShutterButton(Context context,AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context,attrs);
}

public ShutterButton(Context context,AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
{
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
}

interface ShutterButtonListener
{
    public void onShutterButtonFocus(ShutterButton shutterButton,boolean pressed);
    public void onShutterButtonClick(ShutterButton shutterButton);
}

ShutterButtonListener mListener;
boolean mOldPressed;
boolean mTouchEnabled=true;

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if(mTouchEnabled)
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    else
        return false;
}

public void enableTouch(boolean enable)
{
    mTouchEnabled=enable;
}

@Override
public void drawableStateChanged()
{
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    final boolean pressed=isPressed();
    /*
     * When pressing a physical camera button:
     * pressed(true),optional click,pressed(false)
     * Another option that we could use is:
     * pressed(true),pressed(false),optional click...
     * The second set of events occurs when the drawable state gets updated first.
     * To emulate a physical camera button,push back pressed(false) in the event queue.
     * */
    if(pressed!=mOldPressed)//indicates state change
    {
        if(!pressed)//setting to false once shutter has been clicked(true->false)
        {
            post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    callShutterButtonFocus(pressed);
                }
            });
        }
        else//(false->true)clicking the shutter
            callShutterButtonFocus(pressed);
    }
    mOldPressed=pressed;
}

private void callShutterButtonFocus(boolean pressed)
{
    if(mListener!=null)
    {
        mListener.onShutterButtonFocus(this,pressed);
    }
}

public void setShutterButtonListener(ShutterButtonListener listener)
{
    mListener=listener;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick()
{
    boolean result=super.performClick();
    if(mListener!=null &&getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
    {
        mListener.onShutterButtonClick(this);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

In the Activity that uses this ShutterButton:

```
   btn_capture=(com.example.mycameraapp.ShutterButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
    btn_capture.setShutterButtonListener(this);
    btn_capture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    @Override
public void onShutterButtonFocus(ShutterButton shutterButton,
        boolean pressed) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "Shutter button focus called");
    switch(shutterButton.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_capture:
            doFocus(pressed);
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onShutterButtonClick(ShutterButton shutterButton) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "Shutter button click called");
    switch(shutterButton.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_capture:
            doSnap();
            break;
    }

}
```

All the code here has been taken from :

[ShutterButton](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/gingerbread/src/com/android/camera/ShutterButton.java)

[Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/gingerbread/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make `clickable=true` in xml layout or `setClickalbe(true)` in your code.

Anyway, using `performClick` in not a really good way to work with Views in android.

Comment: it worked...thanks...is performClick meant to be used as a fallback for default behaviour in case the OnClickListener is not called?